# Why is React saying invalid prop on src?

Tags: reactjs, image

I'm not sure why?, I've googled it a few times and nothing is coming up...

```
<img src={this.props.user.picture || this.props.user.gravatar} />
 {' '}{this.props.user.name || this.props.user.email || this.props.user.id}{' '}
```

UPDATE:
Sorry, should have included this before

helper method for gravatar

```
userSchema.methods.gravatar = function(size) {
  console.log(gravatar);
  if (!size) {
    size = 200;
  }
  if (!this.email) {
    return `https://gravatar.com/avatar/?s=${size}&d=retro`;
  }
  const md5 = crypto.createHash('md5').update(this.email).digest('hex');
  return `https://gravatar.com/avatar/${md5}?s=${size}&d=retro`;
};
```

and User model for mongoose:

```
var userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: String,
  email: { type: String, unique: true, lowercase: true},      password: String,
  passwordResetToken: String,
  passwordResetExpires: Date,
  gender: String,
  location: String,
  website: String,
  picture: String,
...
```

Comment: what are the values of `picture` and `gravatar`?

Comment: Maybe `picture` or `gravatar` is not a string? Please include your code and data structure in the question.

Comment: Try empty string may be initial rendering is resulting in undefined and src is required attrib `src={this.props.user.picture || this.props.user.gravatar || ''}`

Comment: @Chris, I've tried console.log(gravatar) and nothing is showing in the console - where should I put that to get the values

Comment: when I say "gravatar" I obviously mean "this.props.user.gravatar" :) log that

Comment: @Chris, yea thanks man, I had a brain fart there, had to hit the refresh button last night and take a break